# Spring boot Disable response when https port is hit with http request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, tomcat8

I have a spring boot application in which tomcat is listening on port 8000 over HTTPS. However, when port 8000 is hit with plain http request, the server responds with  http 400.

```
Bad Request
This combination of host and port requires TLS.
```

Is there a way to prevent this? I don't want server to send any response when http://localhost:8000 is requested. Spring boot and tomcat versions are as below:

```
sprint-boot v2.0.0.RELEASE
tomcat v8.5.28
```

Update: application.properties is as below

```
server.port=8000
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-alias=alias
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:key.jks
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store-password=<password>
server.ssl.key-password=<password>
```

Comment: Can you please provide code to support your question? Your spring security configuration file to start with.

Comment: @Prashant I have added my application.properties files contents in the question. Spring security is not being used and is not required anyways.

Comment: What would you expect to happen when callers hit http://localhost:8000? For example, wouldn't you want a HTTP status code back? Also, I'm assuming you are testing with embedded tomcat in your spring boot app. Let us know.

Comment: I just want to send no response.

Comment: @Manish have you got it working? Also, do you know how to customize the message (in case it needs to be shown)?

Comment: @Nitb not yet..

Answer (score 0):

You  enabled  SSL Just  change `server.ssl.enabled=true to`server.ssl.enabled=false

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question.

Comment: What  did  i misunderstand?He says he is  getting 400 Bad and  he did provide his properties file which  shows  SSL is  enabled.Once you  switch  SSL  off  the  400 Bad  Error  disappeared......

Comment: What I wanted that if SSL is enabled and you hit the service with a plain http request (No https), the service should not respond at all. Rather than throwing http 400 (bad request).